# How can I format the image position in CSS Page without image element

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I'm new to CSS and HTML and I don't have enough knowledge to do my task!
**Problem:**
I don't want any space between the mountain image and the place where my blue layer is ending, Any solution?
**NOTE** Don't use the positioning element or any else CSS function, change this code only!

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Merriweather',serif;
}

h1{
    margin-top: 0%;
    font-family: 'Sacramento',cursive;
    font-size: 5.625rem;
}
h2{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}
h3{
    font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
}
.top-container{
    background-color: #E4F9F5;
    position: relative;
    padding: 100px;
}
.mountain{
    padding: 0%;
}
.middle-container{
    /* background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; */
}
.bottom-container{
    /* background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; */
}
.problem{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
 .top-cloud{
    position: absolute;
    right: 300px;
    top: 50px;
}
.bottom-cloud{
    position: absolute;
    /* left: 300px;
    bottom: 300px; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Deepak Kumar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="./assests/icon.jpg">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@700;800;900&family=Merriweather:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="top-container">
        <img class="top-cloud" src="./assests/cloud.png" alt="cloud-image">
        <h1>I'm Deepak.</h1>
        <h2 class="description">a <span class="problem">pro</span>grammer.</h2>
        <img class="bottom-cloud" src="./assests/cloud.png" alt="cloud-image">
        <img class="mountain" src="./assests/mountain.png" alt="mountain-image">
    </div>
      
</body>

</html>
```

I didn't add the whole code, because it was lengthy.
This piece contains enough code for you to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove padding in your `.top-container` .
I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The padding for `top-container` is keeping the `mountain` image from having no space at the bottom of the page. I've slightly altered the padding property to have zero padding on the bottom.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Merriweather',serif;
}

h1{
    margin-top: 0%;
    font-family: 'Sacramento',cursive;
    font-size: 5.625rem;
}
h2{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}
h3{
    font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
}
.top-container{
    background-color: #E4F9F5;
    position: relative;
    padding: 100px 100px 0 100px;;
}
.mountain{
    padding: 0%;
}
.middle-container{
    /* background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; */
}
.bottom-container{
    /* background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; */
}
.problem{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
 .top-cloud{
    position: absolute;
    right: 300px;
    top: 50px;
}
.bottom-cloud{
    position: absolute;
    /* left: 300px;
    bottom: 300px; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Deepak Kumar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="./assests/icon.jpg">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@700;800;900&family=Merriweather:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="top-container">
        <img class="top-cloud" src="./assests/cloud.png" alt="cloud-image">
        <h1>I'm Deepak.</h1>
        <h2 class="description">a <span class="problem">pro</span>grammer.</h2>
        <img class="bottom-cloud" src="./assests/cloud.png" alt="cloud-image">
        <img class="mountain" src="./assests/mountain.png" alt="mountain-image">
    </div>
      
</body>

</html>
```